# Doing multiple MySQL database activities at once in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, web

I'm creating a Reddit clone for web development class. Sorting posts by hotness is the final required thing for me to do.
What I'm struggling with, is binding hotness rating to database entry of given post on website. Because I'm already using a mysqli_query in the while loop, I can't start another query for adding hotness rating.
I read posts suggesting to use arrays but that would consume a lot of server resource since hotness would be calculated again on page refresh.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "database");
if ($link === false) {
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
// this is just reddit's hotness algorithm
function hot($ups, $downs, $date) {
    $s = $ups - $downs;
    $order = log10(max(abs($s), 1));
    if ($s > 0) {
        $sign = 1;
    } else if ($s < 0) {
        $sign = -1;
    } else {
        $sign = 0;
    }
    $seconds = $date - 1134028003;
    return round($sign * $order + $seconds / 45000, 2);
}

$query = "SELECT * from posts";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
if($result) {
    // goes through all posts for upvote/downvote values to calculate hotness
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $post_id = $row['post_id'];
        $time_in_seconds = strtotime($row['timestamp']);
        $hotness_rating = hot($row['upvotes'], $row['downvotes'], $time_in_seconds);
        $hotness_query = 'UPDATE posts SET hotness=$hotness_rating WHERE post_id=$post_id';
        // ideally this would add hotness to post's row in database
        mysqli_query($link, $hotness_query);
    }
} else {
    echo mysqli_error($link);
}
?>
```

Comment: Don't store hotness rating since it is calculated from data already in the database, that's redundant.  Just calculate it when you need it.

Comment: I agree with @AbraCadaver, there may be ways to avoid having to calculate hotness on every page load, but they are probably too advanced for a college course. I would simply calculate it as the page loads.

Comment: That would be way better indeed. Currently I'm just getting post title, content, score and echoing that out as page loads. It's just sorted by date.  $query = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY timestamp DESC". Adding hotness to database and ordering by that just seemed easier to do.

Comment: You can do the actual calculation of hotness in the query and order by that if needed.

Comment: I just did the calculations in the query now and it works fine. Thanks. $query = "SELECT id, username, content, time_stamp, score, title, upvotes, downvotes FROM posts ORDER BY log10(abs(upvotes-downvotes) + 1)*sign(upvotes-downvotes)+(unix_timestamp(time_stamp)/300000) DESC"

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate "hotness" of topic on its update, such as up-vote, down-vote or new message and store it in database at that moment.

This will give you a "hotness" value in database without pointless* recalculations on every refresh and you could simply sort by "hotness".

These recalculations on every refresh is pointless, because if data isn't changed - you will get same result on every refresh and make useless updates to update to same value.

Comment: Hotness will change in time though. This way old posts with high hotness rating would stay high if they aren't updated anymore (upvoted etc).